# jQuery synchronization of functions (only works with alert)

Tags: jquery, synchronization

Here I construct an array:

```
var optionTexts = [];
    $('#stripeMeSubSubCat tr').each(function(){
        if ($(this).find('input:checkbox.subsubcat_chkclass:not(:checked)').length == 0)
            {
                subsubrow_cat_id_no = parseInt($(this).closest("tr").attr("id"));               
                optionTexts.push(parseInt(subsubrow_cat_id_no));
            };          
    });
```

The code below only works whenever the alert is enabled. I have read that this might be due to a synchronization issue. Is there a solution towards the code below? Thank you.

```
$('#stripeMeSubSubCat tr').each(function(){                                      
        myindex = parseInt($.trim($(this).closest("tr").attr("id")));

        if (jQuery.inArray(myindex, optionTexts) == -1) {
             var equal="FALSE";
        }else{
             var equal="TRUE";
            $("#stripeMeSubSubCat tr[id='" + myindex + "'] input").attr('checked', true);       
        };  

        //alert(equal);
});
```

Comment: What's the point in the `equal` variable? It doesn't appear to be used anywhere.

Comment: What does `optionTexts` come from?

Comment: I have added the chunk of code where i construct optionTexts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by "only works whenever the alert is enabled"? You need to describe the difference in behavior in both cases.

Your code has no asynchronous calls, so there shouldn't be  synchronization issue.  However, you seem to be using an integer as a DOM element id. This isn't allowed.

Comment: If I remove // from //alert(equal); in the code and thus enable the alert call, it works.

Comment: Yes, but what works mean? What happens if you include it and what if you don't?

Comment: If i include it then this           $("#stripeMeSubSubCat tr[id='" + myindex + "'] input").attr('checked', true);        is applied where appropriate, whereas if i don't, nothing is applied or maybe is applied before I am actually loading it. I will post the full js code of my file with detailed explanation tomorrow morning. Thank you for your prompt response.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to wait for the DOM to load. Try wrapping this code in:

```
$(function(){
  // put code here
});
```